# spring jdbctemplate what Type for Raw Invalid column Type

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Java - Spring JDBC - oracle

my table looks like

```
id, RAW(16)
name, varchar(50)

@Autowired

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

String queryStr = "insert into myt (id, name) values(:id, :name)";

MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
param.addValue("id", UUID.randomUUID(), Types.Binary);
param.addValue("name", "my name", Types.VARCHAR);

jdbcTemplate.update(queryStr, param);
```

I am getting error `java.sql.SQLException Invalid column Type`

Comment: sorry that was typo

Comment: i fixed that too. pls ignore the compile time

Comment: no plain jdbcTemplate

Comment: Post the stacktrace, that should indicate which of the 2 columns is invalid. My guess is `id` isn't binary, or you might've to convert it to `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `JdbcTemplate` that doesn't support named parameters. With it your requests should be like this:

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
  jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public boolean create(Organization org) {
  var query = """
    INSERT INTO organization
      (company_name, year_of_incorporation, postal_code, employee_count, slogan)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""";
  
  var args = new Object[] { 
    org.getCompanyName(), org.getYearOfIncorporation(), org.getPostalCode(),
    org.getEmployeeCount(), org.getSlogan()
  };
  
  return jdbcTemplate.update(query, args) == 1;
```

If you would like to use **named parameters** you would better use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. With it you can do something like this:

```
public Organization getOrganization(Integer id) {
  var query = """
    SELECT id, company_name, year_of_incorporation, postal_code, employee_count, slogan
    FROM organization
    WHERE id = :ID""";
  var params = new MapSqlParameterSource("ID", id);

  return namedParamJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, params, new OrganizationRowMapper());
}
```

or

```
public boolean create(Organization org) {
  var query = """
    INSERT INTO organization
      (company_name, year_of_incorporation, postal_code, employee_count, slogan)
    VALUES (:companyName, :yearOfIncorporation, :postalCode, :employeeCount, :slogan)""";
  var params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(org);

  return namedParamJdbcTemplate.update(query, params) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers with code as images, post code as actual code.